# Чрезмерный расход памяти при загрузке GIF в ImageView Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, память, imageview, утечка-памяти

Для примера взял абсолютно пустой проект, загружаю изображение в формате .gif в Image

```
// Способ 1
           public class Controller {
        
            public Pane pane;
        
            public void initialize(){
                Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("444.gif").toString());
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(img);
                pane.getChildren().add(imageView);
            }
            }
    
    // UPD Способ 2
    // В этой конструкции потребление памяти уже меньше
    // ~ 150 мб
    // Но этого всё равно недостаточно
    // Оставлю это здесь, пока не встречу подходящего решения.
    
    public class Controller {
    
        public Pane pane;
    
        public void initialize(){
    
            WebView wb = new WebView();
            File f = new File("src/sample/indexx.html");
            // Необходимо создать локальный html файл,
            // указав что в нём будет находиться изображение (наша gif)
    
            wb.getEngine().load(f.toURI().toString());
            pane.getChildren().add(wb);
            wb.setDisable(true);
    
        }
    }
```

Ну а теперь 2 скрина с диспетчера задач.

***Пустой проект :***

[image: Пустой Pane]

***Запуск с Gif анимацией.***

[image: Image .gif]

**У меня есть предположение, что после заряда формата .gif в Image, он превращается в массив Image равный кол-ву кадров в gif.**

**Т.Е например : 1x150 кадров * 1 mb**

Уважаемые гуру JFX, подскажите как правильно использовать такие ресурсы.

Comment: я не гуру и, можно сказать, вообе ничего не понял, потому просто отпишу как совет. Прежде чем говорить об утечках памяти, стоит хотя бы профайлером помяти пробежать и поглядеть, так как эта доп память может быть чем угодно, например каким то статическим буфером или артефактами работы библитеки, которые ещё не успел уничтожить GC - в общем, что угодно тут может быть.

Comment: Утечка памяти немного другое. У вас же нормальная работа с изображением

Comment: Подтянулись зависимости, аллоцировалась память под изображение, захвачены GDI-ресурсы... это не утечка. Пока не доказано обратное с использованием специализированных средств отлова.

Comment: @ArtyMorris Алло ребят проект пустой. Или вы действительно считаете нормой за изображение весом в 1 мб расплачиваться 200 мб памяти ?

Comment: Согласен с Morris. С чего вы взяли что у вас утечка памяти? Только по данным памяти что вы использовали? Утечка памяти вешь не простая и вот так вот с начкоку не скажешь это утечка или нет. Ведь приложение нудна память что теперь не выделять боясь мнимой утечки

Comment: Вы действительно считаете что можно вот так вот сделать анализ? Сходу посмотрев на картинки и 3 строчки кода

Comment: @AzizUmarov Если добавить гифку посолиднее, то будет вообще 700-800. Повторюсь ещё раз, проект голый абсотлютно. Наверняка это всё делается по другому просто.

Comment: @AzizUmarov Вы можете скопировать мой код в пустой Контроллер, скачать с интернета любую гифку приличного размера, и посмотреть что творится в мониторе ресурсов ОС. Какой анализ я должен провести чтобы понять это ?

Comment: Да почему вы считаете это утечкой? gif 1 м ниочем не говорит. Если программе нужно декодировать с анимировать расшифровать и под это нужна память

Comment: @AzizUmarov Если это так важно, то я могу редактировать вопрос назвав это не утечкой, а несоразмерной тратой ресурсов, но тогда этот ответ вряд ли кто-то найдет, с такой же проблемой.

Comment: `У меня есть предположение, что после заряда формата .gif в Image, он превращается в массив Image равный кол-ву кадров в gif.` - скорее всего так и есть, это нормально. Можно заменить gif на серию изображений, допустим, формата png, загружать каждое по отдельности каждый раз заново в процессе анимации. Но в итоге потребление памяти скорее всего будет такое же или хуже, еще и жесткий диск будет постоянно дергать для дозагрузки кадров.

Comment: Так-то диспетчер отображает только размер выделенной памяти, а сколько реально используется в проекте покажет только профайлер. Возможно на обработку гифки как раз выделилось столько памяти, а дальше она освободилась, но куча не уменьшилась просто потому-что))

Comment: @lampa подскажите пожалуйста, как им пользоваться ?

Answer (score 0):

Что-ж, хорошенько погуглив я наткнулся на этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131752/java-memory-issue-with-animated-gif-frames и стало понятно что в Java единственный вариант работы с GIF, это всё делать своими руками.

**Но и этот вариант как утверждают авторы, уже устарел морально.**

Пытаясь использовать приведенный ниже пример, картинка постоянно дергалась и была нечеткой (Возможно это не применимо только к моей GIF), а экономия памяти была посредственной (Удалось выиграть еще 20-30 % от того что было в начале.)

Иначе как костылём, это не назвать но я все же оставлю это здесь :

```
import com.sun.imageio.plugins.gif.GIFImageReader;
import com.sun.imageio.plugins.gif.GIFImageReaderSpi;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/**
 *
 * @author Pasban
 */
public class GifReader {

    private GIFImageReader ir;
    private int count;

    public GifReader(File gif) {
        open(gif);
    }

    private void open(File gif) {
        count = 0;
        ir = new GIFImageReader(new GIFImageReaderSpi());
        try {
            ir.setInput(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(gif));
            count = ir.getNumImages(true);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage(int frame) {
        try {
            return ir.read(frame);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Чтобы получить доступ к конкретному фрему есть общий размер  - `int count`

Вот всё это дело я благополучно закинул в класс расширяемый `Task` передав ему ссылку моей `ImageView` в который мы кладём кадры `Image из BufferedImage.`

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;


public class TestFrame extends Task<Void> {

    private GifReader gifReader;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public TestFrame(GifReader gifReader, ImageView imageView) {
        this.gifReader = gifReader;
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {

        int countFrameNow = 0;
        AtomicBoolean waspaint = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        
        while (true){

            if(!GifOnStartMenu.action){break;}  // Delete this

            waspaint.set(false);
            int finalCountFrameNow = countFrameNow;
           // Platform просит константу,несмотря на то, что мы его всё равно 
           // "подождём"
            
            Platform.runLater(()->{
                this.imageView.setImage(
                        SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(
                                this.gifReader.getImage(finalCountFrameNow),null));
                waspaint.set(true);
            });

            while (!waspaint.get()){
                // Waiting then paint, after sleep
            }
            Thread.sleep(33);

            countFrameNow++;
            
            if (countFrameNow>this.gifReader.getCount()-1){
                countFrameNow = 0;
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

В целом, всё как и говорил Insolor, хоть и стало получше, но в таких ситуациях уповать на GC сомнительная затея... Дергания изображения побороть так и не смог.